# How can I output Active Directory users with date yyyy-mm-dd and OU path?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, ou, get-aduser

How could I write a PowerShell script that will export all AD users by **USER > LAST LOGIN DATE > PASSWORD CHANGE DATE > ROOT OU > SUB OU > SUB OU** with all data separated by cells in a CSV file?

It would be nice to have the everything separated by cells with headers, date output with year first `yyy-mm-dd`, and OU path outputted with root OU first.

[image: Preferred output]

Answer (score 0):

I tested in my environment.

You can use below PowerShell command

```
get-aduser -filter * -properties PasswordLastSet,CanonicalName | select Name,@{Name='Last Login Date';Expression={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.LastLogon).toString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")}},@{Name='Last Password Change Date';Expression={($_.PasswordLastSet).toString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")}},@{Name='OU';Expression={($_.CanonicalName)}} | export-csv 'path-to-csv-file'
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  The year is coming up as 1600 for everyone.  With a regular script, the year shows up correctly so I know it's not an issue with our system.  I think that has to do with how the output is converting.  I will post some similar code which I found that puts the year 1st and correctly. I just don't quite know how to implement it with your code.

Comment: Here is code that works.  I don't really need it to be "inactive users" since I can sort the CSV accordingly by date.  I also don't need the PW change but it would be nice.  Pretty much USER>LAST LOGIN>OU.  thanks

Comment: Import-module activedirectory

$DaysInactive = 730

$time = (Get-Date).Adddays(-($DaysInactive))

Get-ADUser -Filter {LastLogonTimeStamp -lt $time -and enabled -eq $true} -Properties LastLogonTimeStamp |

select-object Name,@{Name="Stamp"; Expression={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.lastLogonTimestamp).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd_hh:mm:ss')}} | export-csv "$($env:USERPROFILE)\Desktop\USER_LOGIN_DATE.csv" –notypeinformation